# Error in Query (Connected Hive with R Studio)

Tags: r, shiny

I have connected Hive with R Studio (Shiny application). Trying to implement a query in R Studio. Below  is the query -

```
function (input){
    hadooptest <- paste("SELECT distinct(varid) FROM
                         staples_us.dfp_networkimpressions 
                         where lineid = input")
}
```

So the input(numeric) is dynamic and coming from UI part of Shiny given by user.
It is showing me an error -

> SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:83 Invalid table alias or column reference 'input'

It seems that it is not recognizing the input while fetching data from Hive.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
function (input){
    hadooptest <- paste("SELECT distinct(varid) FROM
                         staples_us.dfp_networkimpressions 
                         where lineid = ", input)
}
```